# How to populate check boxes in a pdf with data from SQL in asp.net core, c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

So am working on this .Net core project (I am still a beginner). The project aims to print out a populated/filled pdf form with data from Sql. I have managed to fill part of the pdf with data other that the checked boxes. This is giving me hell. The input type = 'text' fills alright, when I print the form... But the checked boxes(input type ='checkbox') are empty... And I don't know what else to do

I have tried looking around to no avail. I can't get resources... Could someone point me to the right direction, or show me how to do it. Below is my code PrintController.cs for populating the form fields

```
public string GetHtml(string clientId) 
{
    var customerData = (from t in _context.ClientProfile
                        where t.FormattedId == clientId select t

                        );
    var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

    foreach (var c in customerData
    {
        sb.AppendFormat(@" 
            <div class='header'>
                <div class='container'>
            <div class='header-top'>
            <p>File no: {0}</p>
        </div> 
        </div>
        </div>   
            <div class='form-area'>
                <div class='container'>
                    <label> Name Of facility: </label> <input type = 'text' value = {1}/>
                    <label> Delivery Point: </label> <input type = 'text' value ={2}/>
            </div>
        </div>", c.FormattedId, c.FacilityCode, c.EntryPoint);
    }
}
```

So the above works well with text input, but nothing shows with checkbox input type....

Comment: Could you please show your `input type ='checkbox'` part?

Comment: What have you tried for a checkbox? I think you want `<input type='CheckBox' checked={0}/>`

Comment: If it's a PDF, which is essentially a static document, not requiring user interaction, then instead of trying to create a checkbox, why not just print "yes" or "no" depending on the value entered? It conveys the same information.

Comment: @nilsK its pretty much the same as the code i wrote, e.g in for the checkbox, `<input id = 'all-input' type= 'checkbox'  value ={0}/> Male` .@Robin  thanks so much mate, that worked. Really appreciate. @ADyson the data i am using is from an android app that had checked boxes, and the pdf was required to relay the check boxes as checked

Comment: I got this working with @ADyson's suggestion